# What does a:arg mean in vimscript?

Tags: vim

Here is an example:

```
function! Mynumber(arg)
  echo line(".") . " " . a:arg
endfunction
```

When you `1,3call Mynumber(getline("."))`, it prints the line number and each of the first three lines of current buffer.

Comment: `:h function-argument`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefix `a:` of a variable indicates that this variable belongs to the argument list (parameter) of the function in which it appears.

See also `:help internal-variables`

```
There are several name spaces for variables.  Which one is to be used is
specified by what is prepended:

        (nothing) In a function: local to a function; otherwise: global
buffer-variable    b:     Local to the current buffer.
window-variable    w:     Local to the current window.
tabpage-variable   t:     Local to the current tab page.
global-variable    g:     Global.
local-variable     l:     Local to a function.
script-variable    s:     Local to a :source'ed Vim script.
function-argument  a:     Function argument (only inside a function).
vim-variable         v:   Global, predefined by Vim.
```

Answer (score 1):

"When you write a Vimscript function that takes arguments you always need to prefix those arguments with a: when you use them to tell Vim that they're in the argument scope."
source (highly recommended reading): http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/24.html